# replace specific link to *******

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

using php or javascript or ajax
how to replace specific link to *******

http://www.google.com/*.*
to
http://www.**********

Comment: What is your question? Clarify it, please.

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Under what context do you expect to get the link?  Is it part of a web page, a url recieved as an http request (like mod_rewrite)?

Comment: What do you mean? You can use `str_replace` in PHP to replace google.com with ********, but something tells me that's not what you mean.

Comment: Ham is to Hamster as Java is to JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean something like (in Javascript):

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
 if (links[i].href == "http://www.google.com/") links[i].href = "http://www.blather.blorg/"
}
```

Tested and works on Firefox 3.

Comment: my page a chat page..... so it may check every link written ??

Comment: yes, it will update the page dynamically each time it is run.

Comment: i tried this an it is not working
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
 if (links[i].href == "http://www.google.com/") links[i].href = "http://www.blather.blorg/"
}


</script>
<a href="www.google.com/">sadasd</a>
</body>
</html>

Comment: of course it doesn't work. "www.google.com/" does not equal "google.com/". and why aren't you including "http://"? the way you made the href, it refers to a subdirectory named "www.google.com", not a different website.

Answer (score 0):

[str_replace()](http://php.net/str-replace)

```
$text = str_replace('google.com', '***', $text);
```

Even if the question is very different: A short JS solution

```
text = text.split("google.com").join("***");
```

Comment: can it be javascript ?....or to be live updated.....it is a chat page

Comment: It has a reason your question is voted "-3" ;) You tag your question with "php" and "java". You ask how to replace "google.com" with "**" in "php or java". What did you expect? You should have clarified your question.

Comment: i don't know what is the problem